# Error when executing hexTapply function of R's hexbin library

Tags: r, data-visualization

I would like to plot visits to a website by screen resolution using R's [hexbin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/hexbin.pdf) package. My current data set is in the following format:

```
Width   Height   Visits
1366    768      507089
1280    800      401926
1024    768      293210
...     ...      ...
```

The complete dataset is available here: http://cl.ly/1t132z0u0l1W

I'd like to plot Width on the x-axis, Height on the y-axis and use Visits to modify cell size and/or color. Hexbin includes a hexTapply function that outputs an array with which we can define cell values, but it does not perform as expected on my data.

I am using the following code:

```
screenres <- read.csv(file="screenres2013.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
width <- screenres$Width
height <- screenres$Height
visits <- screenres$Visits

hbin <- hexbin(width,height,xbins=20,IDs=TRUE)
P <- plot(hbin,type='n')

hVisits <- hexTapply(hbin,visits,sum)
pushHexport(P$plot.vp)
grid.hexagons(hbin,style='lattice',use.count=FALSE,cell.at=hVisits)
```

After executing grid.hexagons(), I receive the following error:

```
Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
In addition: Warning message:
In min(cnt, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

If I then modify hVisits as follows:

```
hVisits[1] <- 1
```

and retry grid.hexagons(), it executes as expected.

I have not encountered this error with any of the examples in the documentation. I don't understand what is causing the issue or why the small modification to hVisits has any effect on the function's execution. Is this a problem with my data or am I missing a crucial step?

I'm very new to R (downloaded it yesterday), so please let me know whether any additional information would be helpful. Thanks in advance for your time.